# Why can the limit of a sequence approach a number and converge, but the limit of the series must approach $0$ to converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, soft-question

My question may not make much sense because I'm still trying to wrap my mind around infinite sequences and series.  I seem to have good working knowledge of when and why to apply a certain tests for a given series, but something just seems like it is missing in my understanding.

Conceptually, why can a sequence converge at any number (except $-\infty$ and $\infty$, which aren't numbers anyway), but the limit of a series must approach $0$ to converge?

Is the reason behind the requirement for the limit of a series approaching $0$ to converge because the series eventually stops summing numbered terms infinitely due to its convergence to a specific number? (Sorry if this question makes no sense)!

And is it acceptable for a sequence to approach any number simply because the sequence isn't being summed?

Comment: You mean thr limit of the summand

Comment: Try to look at the partial sums of the series when $a_n$ does not converge to $0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal excuse my ignorance, but what is a summand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mixing sequences and their sums. The terminology is not very helpful here, I would suggest the following.

Let $a_k$ be any sequence. Then you can define the sequence of partial sums:
$$
  S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \lim_{n\to \infty} S_n.
$$

Given any sequence $S_n$ you can find some $a_k$ such that $S_n$ are the partial sums of $a_k$.

So you see that a series may have any limit, as the sequence do. However if a series $S_n$ has a finite limit, then the corresponding sequence $a_k$ must tend to zero.

Don't confuse the series $S_n$ with its general term $a_k$.

Comment: So is it accurate to say that a series is simply a sequence of partial sums from a given sequence?

Comment: That is my preferred point of view.

Comment: That's interesting because I never could see the relationship between a sequence and a series.

Comment: I say that the terminology does not help because formally the expression: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is a number. So it makes no sense to say that such expression *converges* or *diverges*. But really you are referring to the sequence of partial sums, not to the sum itself.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini It makes perfect sense to say that expression converges or diverges. It is nothing but a limit, and limits can sometimes fail to be numbers, but instead diverge.

Comment: @Potato when $\lim a_n = L$ you can say that the limit is *equal* to $L$ and that the sequence $a_n$ converges to $L$. It is incorrect to say that the limit *converges* to $L$. In the same way one should say that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^2$ is finite or that the series $\sum_{k=1}^N 1/k^2$ converges. Formally it is incorrect to say that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^2$ *converges*.